# How to know when UIPageViewController transition started?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

My app screen contains an **UIPageViewController** that displays some collections and on the top there is a custom horizontal menu with each button corresponding to a specific collection. I have all the things working excepting some details... I want to know when the **UIPageViewController** has started the transition so I can animate my menu buttons. I know it has a delegate but from this I can only get when the user starts a navigation gesture and when the transition has completed.

[Here is a sketch of my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKYbl.png)

Answer (score 0):

After Configuring PageController , there are mainly two delegate methods which gets called whenever a transition either From **Left To Right** or **Right To Left** so following methods :

```
viewControllerBeforeViewController
viewControllerAfterViewController
```

Put your logic here if anything need to handle. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I have already implemented the data source delegate functions and I'm happy with how my collections are displayed. The idea is that I'm looking to synchronize the view controller transition with a button animation,  but I can only get when the transition has completed.

Comment: make uiviewanimatewithduration make it fade in from before delegate to after this makes the view page like previous hiding slowly and other appear same way

Comment: I think we are talking about separate things, I have added a sample image to add more meaning to my question. My UIPageVC is functional and I can navigate through my content, I just need to know the moment when the touch is over and a new view slides in, so I can animate a button from the top menu.